# Click on ember button Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, ember.js, css-selectors

I'm trying to click in this button but I got an error everytime:

```html
<div class="refresh-box">
        <span>
<button type="button" id="ember1328" class="btn-refresh btn btn-default ember-view"><!---->          <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></i>
</button>          update: <font class="color-black"> 11/04/2022 23:31:50</font>
        </span>
      </div>
```

The code that i'm trying to use:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ember581"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div').click()
```

Could anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

To identify the ember button you can use either of the following locator.

**CSS_SELECTOR:**

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn-refresh.btn-refresh.btn.btn-default.ember-view[id^='ember']").click()
```

**XPATH:**

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'btn-refresh') and starts-with(@id,'ember')]").click()
```

---

To avoid synchronization issue use `WebDriverWait()`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn-refresh[id^='ember']"))).click()
```

**OR**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'btn-refresh') and starts-with(@id,'ember')]"))).click()
```

You need following libraries:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet which you have attached and xpath are very different.

```
driver.find_element(By.id,"ember1328");
```

try this

```html
<div class="refresh-box">
        <span>
<button type="button" id="ember1328" class="btn-refresh btn btn-default ember-view"><!---->          <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></i>
</button>          update: <font class="color-black"> 11/04/2022 23:31:50</font>
        </span>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) enabled element and a dynamic element. So everytime you access the application the dynamic part of the value of the *`id`* attribute will always get changed. So you have to construct a ***dynamic***

---

### Solution

To click on the *`<button>`* element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.refresh-box button.btn-refresh.btn.btn-default.ember-view[id^='ember'] i.fa.fa-refresh.fa-2x"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='refresh-box']//button[@class='btn-refresh btn btn-default ember-view' and starts-with(@id, 'ember')]//i[@class='fa fa-refresh fa-2x']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```